# IDLE won't open .py files when I use ctrl+O

Tags: 13.10, python-2.7, idle-python

I've already tried to get .py files to open with IDLE by default, but no luck. I've used every trick you may want to suggest. I really just want to open up IDLE and from there open a .py file from a dialogue box. All I get when I try is a blank IDLE screen that won't close no matter what I do. I open it via the terminal so all I have to do is force the terminal to close and it goes away.

I just want to be able to hit ctrl+o and navigate to my file and have it open in an edit mode so  I can hit f5 to run it. Anyone have a solution for that?

Python 2.7
Ubuntu 13.10 running Cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit this file /usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py:

```
def coding_spec(str):
"""Return the encoding declaration according to PEP 263.

Raise LookupError if the encoding is declared but unknown.
"""
# Only consider the first two lines
str = str.split("\n", 2)[:2]
for line in lst:
```

Replace str with lst:

```
def coding_spec(str):
"""Return the encoding declaration according to PEP 263.

Raise LookupError if the encoding is declared but unknown.
"""
# Only consider the first two lines
lst = str.split("\n", 2)[:2]
for line in lst:
```

I had the same problem and this worked for me.